# For any integer $n\ge 1$, establish the inequality $\tau (n) \le 2 \sqrt n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried to prove this, but I'm stuck because I can't find out how  $\tau (n)$ related to the root of the number. Can anyone show it, or give a hint for this problem?

Comment: If $ab=n$ with positive integers $a$ and $b$, then we have $\min(a,b)\leq \sqrt n$.

Comment: What exactly is the definition of $\tau (n)$ again.  For ever $d|n$ and $d\le \sqrt {n}$ there is a corresponding unique $\frac nd | n$ and $\frac nd \ge \sqrt{n}$.  So there will be equally many divisors below root(n) as a above root (n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say '$d$' is a positive divisor of $n$. Then any integer '$g$', where $g = \frac nd$ is also a positive divisor of $n$.  One of these divisors, '$d$' or '$g$' and if $n$ is a perfect square then both '$g$' and '$d$', must be $\le \sqrt n$.Thus there can be at most $\sqrt n$ divisor pairs $(d,g)$, and hence, $\tau (n) \le 2\sqrt n$.